# Does numpy fromiter create a list when using map during evaluation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-itertools, iterable

In this example I want to know if `numpy.fromiter` creates a list during evaluation. What I want is 'lazy' evaluation where using an iterable avoids allocating/de-allocating a list. Note that the example function is a distance metric and the output is a list of distances between a point a set of points. This is not what the question is about, it's just a example. Also I do need to use `product` because in the real case it will be `itr.product(xyz, repeat=2)`, this is simplified.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as itr
xyz = np.array([[0,0,0], [75,75,25], [50,75,100], [0, 50, 0]], np.int)
wide = len(xyz)
p = np.array([[50, 50, 50]], np.int)
np.fromiter(map(lambda y:
                 np.sum(np.abs(p - y)), itr.product(xyz, repeat=1)),
             np.int, wide)
```

Output `array([150,  75,  75, 100])`

Comment: Are you trying to avoid materializing the iterator's output? You're going to have to do that anyway, in the form of the output array.

Comment: When I use `np.fromiter(list( iterable))` the evaluation time is longer than if I omit the `list()` wrapper.  In either case it is faster than `np.array`, which does require a list.

Comment: But `list(iterable)` without `fromiter` is faster.